# Is Ilog Jrules a opensource software?

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules

Is Ilog Jrules a opensource software?

If yes, can I please know the installation process of Rules Studio and Rules Execution server . I intend to use the eclipse plugin to have Rules Studio to develop business rules.

If no, what can be the alternative options to have rules system for the java web project .Is drools a good option?

Request you to please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ILOG JRules was never open source software.  It is a business rules product created by the Software company ILOG.  ILOG was acquired by IBM in 2009 and ILOG JRules is now sold as IBM Operational Decision Manager (ODM).

You can find two competitive marketing pieces from IBM and Redhat here:

- https://ibmadvantage.com/2014/10/28/ibm-or-droolsred-hat-jboss-brms-whose-rules-rule/
- https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/red-hat-jboss-brms-versus-ibm-websphere-operational-decision-manager

My informed opinion is that IBM ODM is a comprehensive solution for decision management with industry leading features for collaboration between business and technical teams and also industry leading performance.  Redhat Drools is more suited to technical teams.  Source: I used to work in IBM ODM's product management team and did competitive analysis.  I work as an independent consultant in the field of Decision Management now.